# Convert integer to boolean array in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, type-conversion, x509certificate

I need to convert an integer (representing x.509 KeyUsage mask) to boolean array, in Java I have following function available which is working fine:

```
public boolean[] getKeyUsage()
{
    int mask =  144; // Integer.parseInt(testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("keyUsage")); 
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte)(mask & 0xff), (byte)((mask & 0xff00) >> 8) };
    boolean[] keyUsage = new boolean[9];

    for (int i = 0; i != 9; i++)
    {
        keyUsage[i] = (bytes[i / 8] & (0x80 >>> (i % 8))) != 0;
    }
    return keyUsage;
}
```

In this case (144), it should return

> keyUsage = {boolean[9]@976} [0] = true [1] = false [2] = false [3] =
>   true [4] = false [5] = false [6] = false [7] = false [8] = false

When running this in Groovy, I get

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script6.groovy: 22: expecting '}', found ',' @ line
>   22, column 56. w byte[] { (byte)(mask & 0xff), (byte)(( ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting '}', found ',' @
>   line 22, column 56. at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:140)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
>   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
>   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
>   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652) at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643) at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148)
>   at
>   com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93)
>   at

I am a total n00b in Groovy, so sorry if I am missing something obvious

Comment: Have you considered using a `BitSet` instead of a `boolean[]`?  In groovy, a BitSet has all the convenience of an array, plus a `valueOf` constructor that takes a `byte[]`.

Comment: @ataylor, no I haven't because I was not aware of this possibility. I try to keep it in mind, should I need it in the future.

Comment: @ataylor, Anyway, `boolean[]` works just great for me, because I am validating key usage of X.509 certificate and I needed the code to convert the value I set in CSR (ie 144) and see if key usages match with generated certificates key usage but `cert.getKeyUsage()` returns boolean array. But definitely a cool class to know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets the result you need:

```
boolean[] getKeyUsage( int mask ) {
    (7..0).collect { int it ->
        ( ( mask >> it ) & 1 )
    }
}

getKeyUsage( 144 ) == [ true, false, false, true, false, false, false, false ]
```

The error you were getting is because you construct arrays in Groovy with:

```
byte[] bytes = [ 1, 2 ]
```

Not the `new byte[] { 1, 2 }` Java way. But I don't believe you need the byte array...

Comment: I think we need `(8..0).collect { int it ->` as there are a total of 9 key usages available.

Answer (score 2):

In Groovy the following is not valid:

```
int mask =  144;
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte)(mask & 0xff), (byte)((mask & 0xff00) >> 8) };
```

The following is valid:

```
int mask =  144;
byte[] bytes = [(byte)(mask & 0xff), (byte)((mask & 0xff00) >> 8)];
```

You can eliminate the casts if you like:

```
int mask =  144;
byte[] bytes = [(mask & 0xff), ((mask & 0xff00) >> 8)];
```

You can also eliminate the semicolons if you like.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Jeff, I already figured (thanks to Tim), that you can not construct byte array in Groovy as in Java. As a matter of fact, type conversion seems to be the biggest obstacle for me, when porting Java code to SoapUI scripts.  I think I even like your solution better, as I understand what is going on. Thanks again. +1